# Context must be a dict rather than list rendering template

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-templates

I´m making a queryset with django. Now I have a little issue rendering the template. It retuned this error "context must be a dict rather than list". I know that context should be return as a dict, I´m suspecting in the `context['cursos']` line. Anyone can confirm my suspect or give me some solution? thanks in advance

```
class ListCursos( TemplateView):
    model1 = User
    model2 = Course
    template_name = 'plantillas/miscursos.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ListCursos, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        rels = CourseRelUser.objects.filter(user_id=1)
        courses_id=[]
        for rel in rels:
            courses_id.append(rel.c_id)
            return courses_id

        context['cursos'] = Course.objects.filter(id__in=courses_id)
        return context
```

Here is the full traceback error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVseL.png

```
    Internal Server Error: /core/miscursos/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\juand\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\juand\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 204, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "C:\Users\juand\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "C:\Users\juand\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    return template.render(context, self._request)
  File "C:\Users\juand\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 59, in render
    context = make_context(context, request, autoescape=self.backend.engine.autoescape)
  File "C:\Users\juand\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\context.py", line 268, in make_context
    raise TypeError('context must be a dict rather than %s.' % context.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: context must be a dict rather than list.
[20/Jan/2021 11:08:22] "GET /core/miscursos/ HTTP/1.1" 500 76063
```

Comment: Please include the full stacktrace (error) because from what you've included it appears to be getting the context from the super and then using it like a dict & returning it so the error must be elsewhere.

Comment: @markwalker_ Is that what you ask for?

Comment: Sort of, images are generally very helpful. Can you just copy & paste the details of the error which come out in the console (where the server us running in your terminal) into here?

Comment: You have two return statements, so when you reach return courses_id your function ends and the rest of function is not getting executed, so you are only returning the courses_id, which is a list. Also, you are filtering a specific a CourseRelUser with id = 1, but I suspect you want to simply get a user with id = 1. I don't know how your models are structured, but you probably can have a single .filter() and specify that you only want result from the user with id = 1

Comment: @markwalker_ that´s the traceback from console

Comment: @markwalker_ the solution came from Eduardo The first return is not necesary. Thank you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so following the Eduardo's opinion. I proved deleting the `return courses_id` from the for loop and it works fine

```
class ListCursos( TemplateView):
model1 = User
model2 = Course
template_name = 'plantillas/miscursos.html'

def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(ListCursos, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    rels = CourseRelUser.objects.filter(user_id=1)
    courses_id=[]
    for rel in rels:
        courses_id.append(rel.c_id)

    context['cursos'] = Course.objects.filter(id__in=courses_id)
    return context
```

Comment: Glad to know that it helped